# My local Images Are not working Once i added parameters to the url of the component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-props

Before i added the id of the object to the url the images loaded fine but once i added the ID The local images are not loading but url images work. Everything is returning fine in the console and it is the correct pathname.

I have tried using require but it just gives me a huge error with all of my images and some css.

I expect the corresponding image to show

This how the image file looks in my data

```
    img: "img/product-8.94-1.png",


 < img src={require(`../${img}`)} className="img-fluid"
                            alt="product"/>
```

This is the route and Link ( i added id)

```
  <Route path="/details/:id" component={Details} />
 <Link to={`/details/${id}`}>
```

Comment: You should at least show one line of code as an example of what isn't working ...

Comment: I cant post the question because ctrl K searches on google so i have to add the code after i post it.

Comment: Do you get "broken" images in the browser?

Comment: Yes the images do not show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are using relative paths to images in your app, if you changed route path from http://demo.com/details to http://demo.com/details/id the image cannot find the correct path, you got one extra folder details/id.

---

You don't show as how you get the path to the image, but if your image is in your assets folder of reactjs app, then import it like a component.

```
import img from "assets/image.jpg";
```

and then in component add it img src tag like this:

```
<img src={img} className="img-fluid" alt="product"/>
```

If you get images from db, then make sure you use full path to the image.

https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-ardinghelli-sp0yg

Comment: I dont see an assets folder how can i find it or where do i create it?

Comment: Should i just use the full path by using backticks?

Comment: Tell me where do you store your images (what is the location of actual files) in your ReactJS App. Do you use create-react-app or something else?

Comment: yes i used create-react-app this is the absolute path C:\Users\Test\Documents\GitHub\Ecommerce-Store\public\img

Comment: If your component is called Test and is located in `src/components/Test.js` then import photo like this `import myPhoto from "../../public/img/my-photo.jpg"` and then `<img src={myPhoto} className="img-fluid" alt="product"/>`

Comment: @TheGreenLightbulb to put it simply: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-ardinghelli-sp0yg

Comment: Ended  up doing <img src={`../../${img}`} className="img-fluid" alt="product" />

Comment: As i have 100s of items and changing the manually would be a pain haha